# WPF Listview row background blinking effect

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, styles

I use WPF with a `ListView` control.

When a certain parameter is set to True i want the row in the `ListView` to have a blinking animation.

**I have the following code which works but the animation stops once the mouse is over the row with the animation.**

**I want the animation to continue until the parameter is changed back to False.**

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DoBlink}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                            From="Blue" To="LightBlue" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: It seems to me that when your mouse is over, it trigger a background change. You may have to explode the control in Blend and see if it does. Another possibility is that there is something over your background and it might still blink behind. Take a look with Snoop.

Comment: seems the listview default mouseover animation is stopping you... you can control this tru blend

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This situation will require a MultiDataTrigger. Try something like this.

```
<Style
        TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
        <Setter
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Padding="2,2,2,2"
                        Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}"
                                    Value="True" />
                     <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding DoBlink}"
                        Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard
                                    Name="Flash">
                                    <Storyboard
                                        FillBehavior="Stop">
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            From="Blue"
                                            To="LightBlue"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            AutoReverse="True"
                                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}"
                                    Value="False" />
                                <Condition
                                    Binding="{Binding DoBlink}"
                                    Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <StopStoryboard
                                    BeginStoryboardName="Flash" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You will also need to use a MultiDataTrigger to stop the animation when the condition match when you would like it to stop.

EDIT: You can read about MultiDataTriggers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx)

EDIT 2: I have modified the code to work with a control template and added a set of conditions to stop the animation when another item is selected.

EDIT 3: Remove unneeded IsSelected condition.

Comment: I'm getting an exception "Must have non-null value for 'Binding'." , i found its because of the "<Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />" , i replaced that with <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" /> but now it doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: Looks to me like the default styling of the list view is getting in the way. Use the same code but change your Storyboard.TargetProperty to be Control.Foreground. I was able to get it blinking.

Comment: The new example with the control template should work for you.

Comment: Thanks you ,the code still wont work. after applying the change the listview row does blink doesn't display row columns/data. also it only blinks while the item is selected and i wanted it to blink until the paramter is changed.

Comment: Remove the IsSelected Trigger Condition. I will remove it from my example code.

Comment: Also if your data is not showing it may be how you are setting the listviewitem's content field.

Answer (score 2):

Use [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) or [Peter Blois' Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check for what the MouseOver is doing.  I suspect you have a MouseOver handler that would override your StoryBoard.  You can create your own style for your ListBox items (or something inside them) that does not include a MouseOver handler, or use a MultiTrigger to not do the MouseOver if your other condition is true.

Comment: Scott's answer below gives an excellent example.  Feel free to accept his answer if you use his code.